# What happens when you store a numpy array with not enough memory allocated?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management

I was just playing around with np.array and its memory allocation, I expected that if you tried to store an array that was too big for the memory allocation you would just get an error or would just store the first x number of digits. Instead I just got back seemingly random numbers. What is going on behind the scenes here?

```
import numpy as np

def create_new_array(num_list):
  new_array = np.array(num_list,np.int8)
  return print(new_array)

create_new_array([31112 , 32321, 24567,456,324,789])
```

output:
[-120,   65,   -9,  -56,   68,   21]

Changing the input values slightly gives completly differnt outputs and I'm very curiouse as to why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are not random; they are the *complements*. For `int8`, the maximum positive number it can represent is 127, above which the numbers' complements are returned. For example:

```
>>> create_new_array([125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])
array([ 125,  126,  127, -128, -127, -126], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: So I am guessing that the positive 129 intigers are [0  : 127] and the negative are [-1 : -128] right? From what I understand of compliments, you need to subract the number from the largest number in the system. For int8 would this be [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] (seven 1's). How do you subtract numbers like 31000 from this which are much larger and would still put you out of bounds for the memory? or do you do something like 31000 mod 127 and store the result?

Comment: actully no, I think its doing mod256 going from 127 to -128 right? or is it more complicated than that?   test = 31000
  if test%256 <127:
    print(test%256)
  else:
    print(test%256 - 256). This seems to work

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement